# In ER diagram ,is it possible that primary key is not showing?why?

Tags: erd

here,i have seen diagram in which there is no primary key for entity.

in this diagram,item's order_level and price has no primary key.if there is not primary key then it is how to show in data dictionary? 
[image]

Comment: order_level is weak entity? why?

Comment: order_level is reference entity?

Answer (score 0):

It's one of:

1.) All attributes combined are it's primary key

2.) It's a weak identity and the diagram you are showing is incomplete

3.) The diagram is wrong/not showing the primary key. (Seen this many times in textbooks where ER diagrams are explained by example and the key is often missing if it's not needed to explain whatever.)

Comment: here ,order_level entity's attribute min_level,max_level etc are given when the item is created and same as price entity's attribute sale_price,purchase_price etc are given when the item is created .